# new to excel macro vba--how to unhide/hide row based on drop down list value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

By default, I have row 9 hidden in Excel. However, I want to unhide this row if a user selects either Tom or Patrick from the drop down list (A3). Otherwise, I want this row hidden at all time. How would I code this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Row Based on Drop-Down

- Copy this into the sheet module (e.g. `Sheet1`) of the worksheet where you want this to happen.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const CellAddress As String = "A3"
    Const StringsList As String = "Patrick,Tom"
    Const HideRow As Long = 9
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(CellAddress)) Is Nothing Then
        
        Dim Strings() As String: Strings = Split(StringsList, ",")
        
        Dim rrg As Range: Set rrg = Rows(HideRow)
        
        Dim cIndex As Variant
        cIndex = Application.Match(Target.Value, Strings, 0)
        
        If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
            If rrg.Hidden Then
                rrg.Hidden = False
            End If
        Else
            If Not rrg.Hidden Then
                rrg.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```